# C++: Queue with efficient get/put of multiple elements?

Tags: c++, stl, queue

So, I feel like there should be a good, built-in solution for this in C++, but I'm not sure what it is.

I need a queue (ideally thread-safe, but I can wrap it in synchronization myself if need be) that handles groups of bytes efficiently - allowing reads/writes of different sizes.

so, the interface looks like e.g.

```
//removes the first bytesToRead elements from the front of the queue and places them in array; returns the actual number of bytes dequeued
int dequeue(unsigned char *array, int bytesToRead) 
//Adds bytesToWrite elements from array to the end of the queue; does nothing and returns 0 if this would exceed the queue's max size
int enqueue(unsigned char *array, int bytesToWrite)
```

I can write one myself without too much difficulty, but it seems like this ought to be something that's easily done off the shelf.

The best thing in the STL looks like it might be a stringbuf - I'd have to pair calls to sgetc/pubseekoff by hand, but it seems like it would work.

I'm looking to do this as a drop-in replacement for a current queue implementation that's a performance problem; reading in this implementation is O(N) on the amount of data in the queue.  (It's a very naive implementation - every dequeue results in an array copy of the remaining data in the queue.)

Additional requirements (I can implement these in a wrapper if need be):
-I need to be able to specify a maximum size of the buffer
-Read operations should retrieve all available data if less data is available than was requested
-Write operations should do nothing if the requested write would exceed the maximum size and return a failure indicator

So, my questions:
1) is stringbuf sufficient?  Are the read/write operations O(1) relative to the amount of data in the buffer, assuming no resizing is necessary?  (obviously, they'd potentially be O(n) on the number of items requested.)

2) Is there some other class that I'm not seeing that would suffice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect that unless you're just passing pointers to buffers through a queue implemented as a linked list, any benefit you gain from not having to copy data to dequeue will be lost on the additional overhead of having to copy or allocate when you enqueue it.

Comment: @Jon: Sounds as if it isn't the dequeued element being copied that's at issue, but shifting down the entire rest of the queue.  There are plenty of data structures that do better than that.

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't get that from the OPs description.

Answer (score 10):

Hmmm...have you tried the obvious:

```
class queue { 
      std::deque<unsigned char> data;
public:
    int enqueue(unsigned char *array, int bytesToWrite) { 
        data.insert(data.end(), array, array+bytesToWrite);
    }

    int dequeue(unsigned char *array, int bytesToRead) { 
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.begin()+bytesToRead, array);
        // or, for C++11: std::copy_n(data.begin(), bytesToRead, array);

        data.erase(data.begin(), data.begin()+bytesToRead);
    }
};
```

Sorry, I'm not feeling quite ambitious enough at the moment to add locking and the return values you asked for, but neither should be terribly difficult. Instead of fiddling with your return values, however, I'd change the interface to use iterators (or, if you really insist, a reference to a vector).

This is guaranteed to be linear on the number of elements inserted/removed.

Comment: it should be `array + bytesToWrite`

Comment: In your dequeue function, you use pointer arithmetics, it seems to me that the standard specifically says that deque does not allow for "safe access via pointer arithmetics". Or am I mistaken. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/

Comment: @Mikael Persson: it's not pointer arithmetic -- it's iterator arithmetic. `std::deque` provides random access, which means iterator arithmetic is supported, even if/when pointer arithmetic won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a really fast efficient implementation, I would go with a simple circular buffer implementation which means you can do your reads in one or two copies (depending on whether you're wrapping through the end/beginning of your buffer). This allows you to use memcpy which in my experience almost always out-performs looping through lots of elements to do your copying.

If the performance is less critical though I'd go with Jerry's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `std::stringstream` where you push into the queue with `write` and pop off the queue with `read`?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, `std::stringstream` is probably the easiest and best solution.

Another alternative is `std::deque`, it will give you the efficiency you want (constant amortised for all read / write from either end of the queue, and generally much less than O(N) of reallocation if the capacity is exhausted). The only drawback is that `std::deque` does not support pointer arithmetic (because all elements are not necessarily contiguous (in chunks)), so you won't be able to do a block read/write operation, you will have to iterate, as follows:

```
std::deque<unsigned char> buf;

int dequeue(unsigned char *array, int bytesToRead) {
  int result = std::min(bytesToRead, buf.size());
  std::copy(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + result, array);
  buf.erase(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + result);
  return result;
}; 

int enqueue(unsigned char *array, int bytesToWrite) {
  buf.insert(buf.end(), array, array + bytesToWrite);
  return bytesToWrite;
};
```

You should probably make the latter implementation check if the maximum capacity is reached and adjust the resulting value consequently.